# Codeigniter - Accessing variables from a helper file - not a class

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I have a helper file, it has a variable that I want to pass across to a view, but it comes across as empty, so I am a bit unsure if I have the right code or I have overwritten it later on _ though I am sure I have not!

anyway say the variable in ther helper file is an array that contains a list of data, and I use:

```
$this->load->helper('helperfile_helper'); //contains the variable 'productList'
$data['productList'] = $productList;
$this->load->view('page', $data);
```

I would expect that the helper file works like an 'include' with the defined variables available once the helper has been called, is this the casee or have I missed something??

Comment: Can we see the code for `helperfile_helper`?

Comment: thats just an example, but basically it held a list of predefined variables such as $productList = array(blah=>blah);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Helpers` allow you to use `function` in your controller, have a look here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/helpers.html

So you must create a function in your helper file that will return a value.

For example in your helper:

```
if( ! function_exists('random_number'))
{
    function random_number()
    {
return 4;
    }
}
```

and in your controller you can use it:

```
$this->load->helper('helperfile_helper'); //contains the variable 'productList'
$data['random_number'] = random_number();
$this->load->view('page', $data);
```

So `$data['random_number']` will contain 4

Comment: You sir, are a diamond, if I have enough rep I will certainly upvote you for it!

Comment: +1 "So you must create a function in your helper file that will return a value." So means helper can't access my controller variables and vice verse.